# Register more than one mock or service using AutoMock.GetLoose() (Autofac.Extras.Moq)

Tags: autofac

I'm in the process of upgrading our Autofac.Extras.Moq library to the latest version (6.0.0) within our Unit Test project. After upgrading, I noticed tests using: `var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()`, no longer supported the "Provide" method. So I started digging into the documentation for some sort of workaround.

After taking a look at the Getting Started docs (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/v5.2.0/integration/moq.html#getting-started) I've noticed there is a new way of registering mocks and dependent services `using AutoMock.GetLoose(cfg => cfg.RegisterMock(mockA))`. However, some of our tests require more than one Mock injected, and it's not clear to me how to do this.
Take for example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
var mockA = new Mock();
mockA.Setup(x => x.RunA());

var mockB = new Mock();
mockB.Setup(x => x.RunB());

// mockA is automatically registered as providing IServiceA
using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(cfg => cfg.RegisterMock(mockA)))
{
// mockA will be injected into TestComponent as IServiceA
var component = mock.Create();

// ...and the rest of the test
}
}
```

How would I register both mockA and mockB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting both registrations in the `GetLoose` lambda?

```cs
[Test]
public void Test()
{
  var mockA = new Mock();
  mockA.Setup(x => x.RunA());

  var mockB = new Mock();
  mockB.Setup(x => x.RunB());

  // Register both mocks here:
  using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(cfg => {
    cfg.RegisterMock(mockA);
    cfg.RegisterMock(mockB);
  }))
  {
    // ...and the rest of the test
  }
}
```

If you tried this and it didn't work, you should update your question to include both:

- That you tried it AND
- What the exception message or incorrect result was

Otherwise, if this works...

Comment: I had thought I had tried this, but I think I was missing the curly braces. Thanks!